# Emojis turning into weird symbols

Tags: html, css, heroku

I finally finished a website and published it to heroku, but I noticed a strange thing, all emojis turned into strange symbols:

When I used to launch the html file on my pc, this is what I would get
[image: image in pc]

But after it finally started working on heroku, this is what I would get:
[image: Image in heroku publish]

I don't know how to fix this, and there is nothing that I found online that can help. This is the html part that I have:

```
<div class="description">
                    <p>
                      Well, I see you have discovered Candy Lounge!  
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    What makes us special?
                    </p>
                    <p>
                     We host loads of Giveaways! 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                     We have GameNights  
                    </p>
                    <p>
                         We have a very friendly owner , very friendly and helping staff  
                    </p>
                    <p>
                         We have a counting channel and we are trying to be the top on the leaderboard! 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                         Loads of roles for you to collect  
                    </p>
                    <p>
                         Decision of the week! 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                         Open for partners 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                         Memes  
                    </p>
                    <p>
                         A channel for you to post your own amazing and creative art! 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                         A channel for you to post your own great and perfect songs!  
                    </p>
                    <p>
                         A place for you to advertise your own server and grow your own community 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                         Loads of voice channels so we can hear your amazing voices  
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        This is not just a normal server. its a family friendly server where you can have fun and get to know more people!
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        https://discord.gg/DEvtq2k
                    </p>
                </div>
```

How do I turn these symbols into the actual emojis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in order for your emojis to display consistently across various browsers.

UTF-8 character encoding method is used to convert your typed characters into machine-readable code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="description">
    <p>
       Well, I see you have discovered Candy Lounge! 
    </p>
    <p>
      What makes us special?
    </p>
    <p>
       We host loads of Giveaways! 
    </p>
    <p>
       We have GameNights 
    </p>
    <p>
       We have a very friendly owner , very friendly and helping staff 
    </p>
    <p>
       We have a counting channel and we are trying to be the top on the leaderboard! 
    </p>
    <p>
       Loads of roles for you to collect 
    </p>
    <p>
       Decision of the week! 
    </p>
    <p>
       Open for partners 
    </p>
    <p>
       Memes 
    </p>
    <p>
       A channel for you to post your own amazing and creative art! 
    </p>
    <p>
       A channel for you to post your own great and perfect songs! 
    </p>
    <p>
       A place for you to advertise your own server and grow your own community 
    </p>
    <p>
       Loads of voice channels so we can hear your amazing voices 
    </p>
    <p>
      This is not just a normal server. its a family friendly server where you can have fun and get to know more people!
    </p>
    <p>
      https://discord.gg/DEvtq2k
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```